# get real ip from wsl, docker and caddy reverse proxy

Tags: docker, ip, reverse-proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, caddy

i need to get a public ip in my caddy container trough WSL, but whatever i do, i got a virtual IP (always 172.x.0.1).

my **docker-compose**

```yaml
networks:
  personnal:

caddy:
    container_name: caddy
    image: caddy:alpine
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - personnal
```

And my **caddy vhost**

```
dev.my-domain.com {
    reverse_proxy remote_container:80 {
        header_up X-Real-IP {remote_host}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote_host}
    }

    tls internal {
        on_demand
    }
}
```

I found many solutions on the internet, but it is a specific problem: **wsl** + docker + caddy

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

I also could never solve this. I think it's just not implemented in WSL to forward the real ip.

I switched the nginx server to a Raspberry Pi and the same Nginx config forwards the real ip adress just fine.